# How to insert a text in all pages and posts before or after specific places?

Tags: functions, init

I have this simple code below:

```
function func1() {
echo "this is amazing";
}

add_action('reko_hook','func1');
```

Now, I know that I could use ***reko_hook();*** either inside ***index.php*** or ***page.php*** where I want, but I was wondering if there are more pre-defined hooks such as '***init***'.

For example, I could do

```
add_action('init','func1');
```

but it will echo ***this is amazing*** before the header,

The question is, if there are other pre-defined hooks to specify the location of the function output ***this is amazing*** to be placed:

1. After the header, before the Page/Post title.
2. After the header, after the Page/Post title.
3. Before Footer.
4. After the Footer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to before or after the content as well in a similar fashion.  I use this code:

```
function rt_before_after($content) {
    $beforecontent = 'This goes before the content.';
    $aftercontent = 'And this will come after.';
    $fullcontent = $beforecontent . $content . $aftercontent;

    return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rt_before_after');
```

You could use it similarly with the_title,.

The reko_hook() you have likely came with your theme or a different plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is not THAT simple to answer. In order to output a content somewhere in a WordPress theme, there must be either a hook, function, etc. in that particular place.

For example, if you want to add a string to the title, you can hook to the title using the following hook:

`add_filter( 'the_title', 'myFunction');`

But you can not simply add a string between two `DIV` element which have a structure as below:

`<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</div>`

If you want to do something like this, you have to go through PHP functions such as `preg_replace()` and bunch of other tasks to find the part that you want to alter, which is not always the best approach.

So, to echo your content before/after the title, you can use the filter that i provided to you.

To add something to footer, you can set a priority for your hook. Notice that you can't output something after the footer hook, since there is no hook afterward, unless you define your own function or custom hook for that purpose.

So, you can try using the following code to output your content after every other action has been fired:

`add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function', 999 );`

and change the priority from 999 to 1, in order to reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be styled in any special way different from the elements to which the text is being added? If not, this could probably be solved with some simple CSS using the :before and :after selectors to add content to whichever element you select.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
header:before , h1:before, footer:before
{content: "this is amazing ";}

header:after , h1:after, footer:after
{content: " this is amazing";}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>My Header</h1>
</header>
<p>Your awesome page content</p>
<footer>
<b>Note:</b> For the content property to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```